# Problem for count array position in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, arrays, count, php-7.2

My code works but this warning is generated:

**Code:**

```
$config = ["title" => "Title Test","Body" => "Body Test"];

if(count($config["title"]) > 0) {

  echo "OK";

} else {

  echo "ERROR";

}
```

**Warning:**

> [25-Feb-2020 13:32:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/...

Comment: The warning is explaination enough I'd have thought. It is telling you that `$config["title"]` is not an array or an object that implements Countable...

Comment: Because you targetted $config["title"], which is the output is string "Title Test". The parameter inside count() must be array. If you want to check the string type, use empty() function.